# how to enable jquery script to support dynamic ids

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div popup script which works as intended - [see working version here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwJrYX). I wish to use this code within a php loop but it seems the div id is a fixed reference and as such I cannot use this within a loop as the div id can only be referenced one time.

I am looking for a solution to somehow allow the jquery popup script to support dynamic div id's but not sure how to do that.

Here is my html/php code where i can assign a dynamic div id:

`$counter` is a number, the number increases on every loop i.e. inline-popups1, inline-popups2 etc..

```
$content = "<!-- Jquery reference -->
<div id='inline-popups".$counter."'>

<!-- Popup link -->
    <a href='#popup".$counter."'>Popup Link</a>
  </div>

<!-- Popup itself -->
<div id='popup".$counter."' class='white-popup mfp-with-anim mfp-hide'>
  <p>content goes here</p>
</div>";
```

Here is the jquery - as you can see `$('#inline-popups')` is a fixed referenced. I need it to support the dynamic references as shown above.

```
// Inline popups
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#inline-popups').magnificPopup({
      delegate: 'a',
      removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
      callbacks: {
        beforeOpen: function() {
           this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
        }
      },
      midClick: true // allow opening popup on middle mouse click. Always set it to true if you don't provide alternative source.
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple divs?  Can't you reuse one div and change the content?

Comment: the only one that needs to be dynamic is the first div `<div id='inline-popups".$counter."'>` as thats what is referencing the jquery script.. but how to make the jquery accept that call ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to make the id dynamic like that.  But like I asked, why can't you just use one div?

Comment: I tried using one div to cover all iterations of the loop but only the data from the first iteration were click-able, the rest were not. Couldn't understand why they didn't work

Comment: Then that is the real problem you should post about.  We can help you with that.

Comment: i figured it didn't work because each iteration in the loop needed its own but since you can't have div's with the same id i am trying to see if we can make it dynamic

Comment: But you only need ONE div.  Make the content of the div dynamic.

Comment: ,Why don't you use a class instead? That's said you can use as selector: `$("[id^='inline-popups']")`

Comment: @A.Wolff i tried your suggestion but now none of the links for the popup work.. your suggestion sounds promising but can you explain how it works ? this part specifically `id^=`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ It works as expected here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXBpYg

Comment: @A.Wolff, nice one! that works!! :) can you please offer it as a solution so i can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `startsWith` CSS attribute selector as described [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("[id^='inline-popups']")
```

But you should/could use class instead.